# Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct (CS1518)

Tags: c#, struct, enums

simple code here and the answers I find don't seem to work.

I'm using

SharpDevelop Version : 3.2.1.6466
.NET Version         : 2.0.50727.5485

The problem is the error code 
Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct (CS1518).

Any ideas?

Program.cs codes:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Threshold
{
public class Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {
        Heritage YOLO = new Heritage();
        YOLO.Fractal();
    }
}
    static void Main()
    {
       //do nothing
    }
}
```

The cs file it calls is:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Threshold
{
public class Heritage
{
int Fractal()
{
    //Do stuff.
}
}

internal partial class DefineConstants
{
    public const string DRIVERPATH = "d:\\tc\\bgi";
}

}
```

Please help with a fix.
Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Your main method is outside the class. Put it inside.